# Problem with two UpdatePanels and Validators

Tags: asp.net, ajax, validation, updatepanel

In the following code...

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
            Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="This field is required">
            *</cc1:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Why the content of `UpdatePanel2` is affected by the `RequiredFieldValidator`which exists in the `UpdatePanel1` !!!

They're splitted and the `UpdateMode` for them is set to `Conditional` !!!

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ValidationGroup property like the following,

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ValidationGroup="UpdatePanel1"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:requiredfieldvalidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" controltovalidate="TextBox1"
            display="Dynamic" errormessage="This field is required" ValidationGroup="UpdatePanel1">               *</cc1:requiredfieldvalidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="UpdatePanel1" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClick="Button2_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```